# What do I select in order to add this blend into another? (append)

Tags: append

Okay, so I need to add trees into a city build, but the append feature is not working. I believe I have done everything right, but when I select all the parts, nothing shows up except for that object (see in images). Copy and paste isn't working too. @Chris said to double tap object (once file is opened, but this issue popped up. [Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMZtn.jpg)

[image: Images]

Comment: @Chris Please view the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Doubletap on "Object" and choose the object which you want to append.